# How to use regular expression in JSON as key

Tags: json, angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

Is it even possible to do so? I didn't find a single solution on the internet. I'm working on Angular 6 project. I've to translate few strings and for that I'm maintaining one `en-US.json` file in `i18n` folder. JSON is like this:

```
"words": {
  "Car": "Wagen",
  "Ship": "Schiff",
  "Flight": "Flug",
  "*": "",   // <------------ HELP NEEDED
}
```

I don't want to convert other strings whatsoever. Can I use regular expression to ignore them. Leaving them unattended is giving me strings like:

```
words.train
words.helicopter
```

Please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: Do you just want to iterate over the keys in your JSON object and find the ones that start with UN and end with ULLY?

Comment: Yes, but i want to deal with them separately

Comment: I mean handle starting with UN and ending with ULLY separately

Comment: Where does regular expression come in to play here? I would just iterate over keys and say "if starts with UN, do one thing, if ends with ULLY do another". Though that is brittle if you can't ensure that you would never have a legitimate property starting with / ending with that magic string.

Comment: @Dean, I've changed the question. Please help

Comment: if you don't want to convert other strings, simply don't add any translations. `"*": ""` is not needed. Depend on your settings, the default language should show up when no translation available.